# How to match group compulsory if it occurs?

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I'm having a string

```
Name: abc
        No:  1234
new: yes
DOB:    06-07-1992
     sal:  40000
```

In this string, I want to match the name, dob, no and sal.

The new should be matched if it comes otherwise no need to match. I have tried regex,
`(?:name:\s*(\S+)).*?(?:no:\s*(\d+)).*?(?:new:\s*(yes))?.*?(?:dob:\s*(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})).*(?:sal:\s*(\d+))`

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/dCZEF0/1/).  I made the group `(?:new:\s*(yes))?` optional. But it is not matching if it occurs. How to match that group compulsory if it occurs? Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wrap the dot matching pattern with an optional group where the group you need to match is made *obligatory*:

```
name:\s*(\S+).*?no:\s*(\d+)(?:.*?new:\s*(yes))?.*?dob:\s*(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}).*sal:\s*(\d+)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dCZEF0/2)

when you made it optional, it just matched an empty string and thus the group was empty. In `(?:.*?new:\s*(yes))?`, the `.*?` will match any chars as few as possible (each time this pattern is skipped and the `new:\s*(yes)` is tried, and only when it is not matched, `.*?` is expanded). And since `new:\s*(yes)` is obligatory, it will be tried at least once, and if the matching substring is present, it will be captured.